# Three-Way Button Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a "three-way" button toggle in javascript. I've already created the base functionality here:

https://codepen.io/nico-cardenas/pen/GRoexoL

You can toggle the buttons when you click on it - but I can't seem to figure out how I can trigger the "toggle" if you click on another button (not the one you originally clicked).

I was thinking of saving the currently clicked button to a variable but I'm still lost.

```js
var btn = $('.btn');
var isActive = false;

btn.click(function() {
  if (!isActive) {
    $(this).css({
      'backgroundColor': 'blue'
    });
    isActive = true;
  } else {
    $(this).css({
      'backgroundColor': 'red'
    });
    isActive = false;
  }
})
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn"></div>
<div class="btn"></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly: Do you want to toggle button A by clicking button B?

Comment: Sorry if my explanation is a bit confusing. Basically, aside from toggling the buttons via clicking on them, you can also trigger their "toggled" state by clicking another button (in my case, yes, button B) :)

Comment: That is no clearer

Comment: So you wish to have a "shared state" for multiple buttons, and whenever this state is updated (no matter where from), so are the buttons?

Comment: Exactly sir! The actual app will have multiple buttons that can play an mp3 file when clicked and can be toggled off when clicked again.

If there's an active mp3 file playing and you click on a different button, it will stop the currently active mp3, update the state of the currently active button back to OFF, play the new mp3 file, and update the state of the "new" active button to ON. You can also click on the currently active button again if you want to toggle the mp3 to OFF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean this?

```js
const btn = $('.btn');

btn.on("click", function() {
  btn.not(this).removeClass("active"); // remove all other buttons's active
  $(this).toggleClass("active"); // toggle this button
})
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn"></div>
<div class="btn"></div>
```

For audio

```js
const btn = $('.btn');

btn.on("click", function() {
  let audio;
  btn.not(this).each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active"); // remove all other buttons's active
    audio = $("#" + $(this).data("id")).get(0); // DOM audio
    if (audio) {
      audio.pause();
      audio.currentTime = 0;
    }
  })
  audio = $("#" + $(this).data("id")).get(0); // DOM Audio
  if ($(this).is(".active")) {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
  } else audio.play(); // start the DOM audio  
  $(this).toggleClass("active"); // toggle this button
})
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn" data-id="mp3_1"></div>
<div class="btn" data-id="mp3_2"></div>

<audio id="mp3_1" src="https://freesound.org/data/previews/171/171671_2437358-lq.mp3" />
<audio id="mp3_2" src="https://freesound.org/data/previews/254/254819_4597795-lq.mp3" />
```

Comment: Exactly this! My only concern at the moment is I'm going to use this behavior in toggling audio mp3 files. Here's the flow:

1.) You click on any button, it will play an audio file.
2.) You click on that same button, it will toggle the audio off.
3.) You click on any other button (while an active audio is playing), it will also toggle the currently playing audio to off and while at the same time, playing a new audio file.

Apologies if I suck at explaining > <

Comment: See update. It will start and stop on click of same and stop other sounds when clicked

Comment: Thank you sir! I just noticed that clicking the button again doesn't stop the audio? It only stop the audio if you click on a different button.

Comment: Look again. I realised this and fixed it

Comment: You nailed it sir! I spent hours trying to figure this out and you made it work like in 5 mins.  I need more coding practice ><

Thanks soo much!

Comment: It was not trivial. I had to look up how to get the audio DOM from jQuery and to reset instead of just stopping. Otherwise it would have been 2 minutes ;))))

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it via `.on`:

```js
var btn = $('.btn');
var isActive = false;

btn.on('click', (function() {
  if (!isActive) {
    $(this).css({
      'backgroundColor': 'blue'
    });
    isActive = true;
  } else {
    $(this).css({
      'backgroundColor': 'red'
    });
    isActive = false;
  }
}));
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn"></div>
<div class="btn"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It does not work as requested. Actually it is identical to OP's version except for .on